# PYQT5 Python : How to add QComboBox in QTreeWidget column header?

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

is it possible to add a QComboBox in column header from QTreeWidget ?

I want a **QComboBox** next to or under `AI` in the header. (I have different kind of AI that's why).

[image: My QTreeWidget]

I know that it's possible to add *QComboBox* as *QTreeWidgetItem*. But in header i didn't find out.
Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know you can add any widgetitem under header of qtreewidget and here is the code for doing it.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QTreeWidget, QTreeWidgetItem, QPushButton, QLabel, QDialog, QVBoxLayout, QApplication, QLineEdit)
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QPushButton, QDialog, QTreeWidget,
                             QTreeWidgetItem, QVBoxLayout,
                             QHBoxLayout, QFrame, QLabel, QComboBox,
                             QApplication)

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.treeWidget = QtWidgets.QTreeWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.treeWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(90, 50, 256, 192))
        self.treeWidget.setObjectName("treeWidget")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        #initialize top level items
        self.topLevelItem1 = QTreeWidgetItem(self.treeWidget)
        
        #add those top level in treewidget
        self.treeWidget.addTopLevelItem(self.topLevelItem1)

        #create button
        self.ButtonWidget=QtWidgets.QPushButton("Press")
        self.ButtonWidget.clicked.connect(self.AddCombo)
        #add button to tree widget
        self.treeWidget.setItemWidget(self.topLevelItem1, 0, self.ButtonWidget)
        
        
        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)


    def AddCombo(self):
        #add combo box on button press
        self.QcomboWidget=QtWidgets.QComboBox()
        self.QcomboWidget.addItem("item1")
        self.treeWidget.setItemWidget(self.topLevelItem1, 1, self.QcomboWidget)

        

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.treeWidget.headerItem().setText(0, _translate("MainWindow", "Designation"))
        self.treeWidget.headerItem().setText(1, _translate("MainWindow", "AI"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```